# How to calculate torque requirement for vehicle with Mecanum wheels?

Tags: motors, torque, mechanical

What are the changes specific to mecanum wheels when calculating torque requirements for a vehicle. I have the data for the vehicles mass, top speed and top acceleration.

Comment: if you are familiar with torque for general wheels, then why are mecanum wheels different - and how would you then account for the changes?

Comment: I was thinking that due to the orientation of wheels the torque requirement would change. I need to  find out what  would be the torque While moving sideways and turning

Answer (score 0):

An ideal Mecanum Wheel does not transfer all the torque towards the motion, unlike an ideal normal wheel.

The torque for one Mecanum wheel can be calculated using the formula :

**T = ((mxa)/4√2)xr**

where m is the mass in kg that needs to be carried by the Mecanum system,
a is the acceleration of the system,
and r is the radius of the Mecanum wheel.

Comment: A reference for the equation would improve this answer.